# Change in inequality condition from $ x \ge a $ in the definition of O(x) to $ x \ge 1 $ in an application of O(x)

Tags: number-theory, inequality, asymptotics

In the book "An Introduction to Analytic Number Theory" by Tom M. Apostol, section 4.6, Theorem 4.8 has this sentence:

> Hence (24) implies $ S(x) - S(x/2) = O(x) $. This means that there is some constant $ K > 0 $ such that $ S(x) - S(x/2) \le K(x) $ for all $ x \ge 1 $.

But that isn't the definition of $ O(x) $, is it? Section 3.2 defined $ O(x) $ like this:

> If $ g(x) > 0 $ for all $ x \ge a $, we write $ f(x) = O(g(x)) $ to mean that the quotient $ f(x)/g(x) $ is bounded for $ x \ge a $; that is, there exists a constant $ M > 0 $ such that $ |f(x)| \le Mg(x) $ for all $ x \ge a $.

In the definition of $ O(x) $ we only need the inequality $ |f(x)| \le Mg(x) $ to hold for $ x \ge a $ (not $ x \ge 1 $).

How then in Theorem 4.8, does it claim that the inequality must hold good for $ x \ge 1 $?

Comment: $S(x) - S(x/2)$ is bounded on $[1,a]$ for every $a \geqslant 1$. A fortiori, $\frac{S(x) - S(x/2)}{x}$ is bounded there. Going down to $1$ may require us to pick a larger constant, but it doesn't affect the existence of a constant.